# How to use scaleBand.domain() for discrete data in D3 v6 without hardcoding the data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to create a bar chart for the comparison of global food waste. I am using a CSV file with format like this:

```
Countries,Household_Food_Waste
Australia,102
Austria,39
Denmark,81
Netherlands,50
New Zealand,61
Norway,79
Sweden,81
United Kingdom,77
United States of America,59
China,64
Japan,64
Poland,56
Russian Federation,33
Finland,65
Italy,67
France,85
Belgium,50
```

However, when I try to create xScale for the countries' data, I am not sure about what should be put to the domain value:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
               .domain()
               .rangeRound([padding ,width])
               .paddingInner(0.05);
```

So far, all solutions that I have found demand me to hard code all the countries' name, which is very tedious in this case.

Does anyone have the solution for the domain in this case without hardcoding?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you loaded your CSV into an array?

Comment: No, I did not convert it into an array, but what should I do after that for the domain?

Comment: If you have your CSV as an array you can get the countries via `const countries = myArray.map(obj => obj.Countries)` and then pass that into the `domain`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your CSV as an array you can get the countries via

```
const countries = myArray.map(obj => obj.Countries)
```

And then pass that into the domain

```js
const csv = `Countries,Household_Food_Waste
Australia,102
Austria,39
Denmark,81
Netherlands,50
New Zealand,61
Norway,79
Sweden,81
United Kingdom,77
United States of America,59
China,64
Japan,64
Poland,56
Russian Federation,33
Finland,65
Italy,67
France,85
Belgium,50`;

const myArray = d3.csvParse(csv);

const countries = myArray.map(obj => obj.Countries);

console.log(countries);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```